# ¿Como se prodria calcular el iva dependiendo del pais, y dependiendo del iva que tenga o si no lo tiene Iva? php

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Necesitaria calcular el iva en php codeinigter 3

- dependiendo del pais
- dependiendo del producto que sea unos seran el 21% otros 3%
- si no tiene Iva

Answer (score 1):

Puedes simplemente tener una tabla con todos los porcentajes según el pais y clase de producto, al igual que se hace en la legislación española, por ejemplo dentro de este país hay impuesto tipo 1 (IVA reducido), tipo 2 (IVA normal), tipo 3 (sin IVA) y según eso hacer una regla de tres para sacar el valor final.

Básicamente debes indicar a que grupo pertenece cada producto dentro de ese país

| pais | id_impuesto | cantidad_impuesto |
| --- | --- | --- |
| es | 1 | 0 |
| es | 2 | 3 |
| es | 3 | 21 |
| nl | 1 | 21 |
| de | 1 | 23 |

```sql
select * from putos_impuestos where pais = "es" and id_impuesto = 3;
```

En base a eso incluso podrías hacer un indexado pero no creo ni que se necesite porque no creo que se haga tan grande y sería contraproducente.

O simplemente definir cantidades comunes de impuestos sin tener en cuenta el país lo cual no suele ser relevante y de esta forma podrás reaprobechar los valores

| id_impuesto (autoincremental) | cantidad_impuesto |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 21 |
| 4 | 23 |

```sql
select * from putos_impuestos where id_impuesto = 3;
```

Y luego en el producto puedes decirle simplemente a que id de impuesto pertenece

| producto | id_impuesto |
| --- | --- |
| rosita | 3 |
| papel de baño | 1 |
| cremita para las manos | 2 |
| tabaco pal papa aleman | 4 |

```sql
select id_impuesto from productos_to_guapos where producto = "rosita";
```

Y en base a eso ya haces la regla de tres para sacar el valor final

https://forum.codeigniter.com/showthread.php?tid=66422